# Is there way to work with lru_cache while returning mutable objects without side effects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, caching, functools

When returning a mutable object (such as a `numpy.ndarray`) from an lru_cached function, any change to the returned object - will affect the cached object.

This generally makes sense, however can also be confusing.

see the following example

```py
In [13]: from functools import lru_cache
    ...: import numpy as np
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: @lru_cache
    ...: def cached_function(param):
    ...:     print(f"running cached_function on: {param}")
    ...:     return np.array([param])
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: for number in [100, 200, 100]:
    ...:     res = cached_function(number)
    ...:     res *= 5
    ...:     print(res)
    ...:
running cached_function on: 100
[500]
running cached_function on: 200
[1000]
[2500]
```

Is there anyway to use `lru_cache` (or similiar) without this side effect?

Should returning mutable objects from cached functions be avoided?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54909677/12641958) addresses this behavior, essentially you'll want to return a copy of your array from your decorated function. Depending on your use case, this may be problematic due to the amount of memory being utilized doubling.

Comment: Why are you using the cache?  To save memory, or computation time?  This isn't a very common task.

Comment: @hpaulj to save time - of course this is just an example function.
a real use case will include IO or intense CPU work